# Why does numba not work with this nested function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, precompile

I reported the described bug here: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/3095 , if anyone is interested in the solution of the problem.

I am trying to precompile a minimzation running on 3D time series data with numba. As a first step, I wanted to define a cost function, but this already fails. Here is my code:

```
from numba import jit

@jit
def tester(axis,data):
    def lineCost(pars):
        A=pars[0]
        B=pars[1]
        return np.sum((A*axis+B - data)**2)
    return lineCost([axis,data])

tester(1,2)
```

This yields a "Not implemented" error:

```
~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numba/lowering.py in lower(self)
    171         if self.generator_info is None:
    172             self.genlower = None
--> 173             self.lower_normal_function(self.fndesc)
    174         else:
    175             self.genlower = self.GeneratorLower(self)

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numba/lowering.py in lower_normal_function(self, fndesc)
    212         # Init argument values
    213         self.extract_function_arguments()
--> 214         entry_block_tail = self.lower_function_body()
    215
    216         # Close tail of entry block

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numba/lowering.py in lower_function_body(self)
    237             bb = self.blkmap[offset]
    238             self.builder.position_at_end(bb)
--> 239             self.lower_block(block)
    240
    241         self.post_lower()

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numba/lowering.py in lower_block(self, block)
    252             with new_error_context('lowering "{inst}" at {loc}', inst=inst,
    253                                    loc=self.loc, errcls_=defaulterrcls):
--> 254                 self.lower_inst(inst)
    255
    256     def create_cpython_wrapper(self, release_gil=False):

/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     75                 value = type()
     76             try:
---> 77                 self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
     78                 raise RuntimeError("generator didn't stop after throw()")
     79             except StopIteration as exc:

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numba/errors.py in new_error_context(fmt_, *args, **kwargs)
    583         from numba import config
    584         tb = sys.exc_info()[2] if config.FULL_TRACEBACKS else None
--> 585         six.reraise(type(newerr), newerr, tb)
    586
    587

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numba/six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    657         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
    658             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
--> 659         raise value
    660
    661 else:

LoweringError: Failed at object (object mode backend)
make_function(closure=$0.3, defaults=None, name=$const0.5, code=<code object lineCost at 0x7fd7ada3b810, file "<ipython-input-59-ef6835d3b147>", line 3>)

File "<ipython-input-59-ef6835d3b147>", line 3:
def tester(axis,data):
    def lineCost(pars):
    ^
[1] During: lowering "$0.6 = make_function(closure=$0.3, defaults=None, name=$const0.5, code=<code object lineCost at 0x7fd7ada3b810, file "<ipython-input-59-ef6835d3b147>", line 3>)" at <ipython-input-59-ef6835d3b147> (3)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
This should not have happened, a problem has occurred in Numba's internals.

Please report the error message and traceback, along with a minimal reproducer
at: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/new

If more help is needed please feel free to speak to the Numba core developers
directly at: https://gitter.im/numba/numba

Thanks in advance for your help in improving Numba!
```

Could you help me in understanding which part of the code causes problems for numba? That would be of very big help. Thank you!

Best,
Malte

Comment: "This should not have happened, a problem has occurred in Numba's internals.

Please report the error message and traceback, along with a minimal reproducer
at: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/new

If more help is needed please feel free to speak to the Numba core developers
directly at: https://gitter.im/numba/numba" Seems pretty clear what your next steps are.

Comment: OK, thanks, I thought I might miss something essential and basic as I really just started with numba. Then I'll proceed as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it seems this was a bug that was removed in the newest release :)
https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/3095

Answer (score 1):

Avoid global variables (data and axis are global in lineCost), avoid functions which contains functions and avoid lists ([axis,data]).

**Working example**

```
from numba import jit

@jit
def lineCost(axis,data):
    return np.sum((axis*axis+data - data)**2)

@jit
def tester(axis,data):
    return lineCost(axis,data)

tester(1,2)
```

Most of this things should work in the latest release, but using the latest features which often contains some bugs or some details which aren't supported, isn't recommendable.

Even if this would work, it wouldn't suprise me much, if the performance is less than expected.